# How to bind a function in view model to a custom view in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom textfield:

```
struct InputField: View {

    var inputText: Binding<String>
    var title: String
    var placeholder: String
    @State var hasError = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 5.0) {
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Spacer()
            }
            TextField(placeholder, text: inputText).frame(height: 50).background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .border(hasError ? Color.red : Color.clear, width: 1)

        }
    }
}
```

my view model is:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var username = "" {
        didSet {
            print("username is: \(username)")
        }
    }
     func checkUsernameisValid() -> Bool {
        return username.count < 6
    }
}
```

and my final login view:

```
@ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

var inputFields: some View {
        VStack {
            InputField(inputText: $loginViewModel.username, title: "Username:", placeholder: "  Enter your username", hasError: $loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid())
            InputField(inputText: $loginViewModel.password, title: "Password:", placeholder: "  Enter your password", hasError: $loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid())
        }
  }
```

Now this complains at `hasError:$loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid()` that I cannot bind a function to the state var `hasError`.

How can I make this work by still using the function `checkUsernameisValid()` to update my custom textfield view ?

One way I can solve this is by using another published var in my view model

```
@Published var validUsername = false

 func checkUsernameisValid() {
    validUsername = username.count < 6
}
```

and keep calling this function in the didSet of my username var

```
@Published var username = "" {
    didSet {
        print("username is: \(username)")
        checkUsernameisValid()
    }
}
```

finally use the new published var to bind the hasError:

```
hasError: $loginViewModel.validUsername
```

My question is, is this the only way ? i.e use @published var for binding, and I cannot use standalone functions directly to do the same thing instead of using more and more @Published variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need binding for error. The `InputField` will be updated by `inputText`, so you just need a regular property, like

```
struct InputField: View {

    var inputText: Binding<String>
    var title: String
    var placeholder: String
    var hasError = false       // << here !!

// ...
}
```

and now pass just call

```
InputField(inputText: $loginViewModel.username, title: "Username:", placeholder: "  Enter your username", 
     hasError: loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid())   // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

var inputFields: some View {
        VStack {
            InputField(inputText: $loginViewModel.username, title: "Username:", placeholder: "  Enter your username", hasError: loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid())
            InputField(inputText: $loginViewModel.password, title: "Password:", placeholder: "  Enter your password", hasError: loginViewModel.checkUsernameisValid())
        }
  }
```

The function works on the actual value on the bound variable, not the binding itself.